# C++ Function (RemoveSortedDuplicates) not deleting more than one duplicated node

Tags: c++

I want to write a function that returns true if there are nodes with duplicated values and removed successfully in a sorted singly linked list, else it returns
false. When I test it at main() like this:

```
int main() {

    struct node* head = NULL;
    struct node* head1 = NULL;
    struct node* head2 = NULL;

    AddToEndv2(&head, 1);AddToEndv2(&head, 2);AddToEndv2(&head, 3);AddToEndv2(&head, 4);AddToEndv2(&head, 5);AddToEndv2(&head, 15);AddToEndv2(&head, 70);
    //AddToEndv2(&head1, 30);AddToEndv2(&head1, 40);AddToEndv2(&head1, 50);AddToEndv2(&head1, 40);AddToEndv2(&head1, 30);AddToEndv2(&head1, 30);

    Print(head);
    cout << "\n";
    //Print(head1);
    //cout << "\n";
    
    cout << "RemoveDuplicatesSorted function output:" << endl;
    cout << RemoveDuplicatesSorted(head);
    cout << "\n";
    Print(head);
    cout << "\n";
```

I get this output, where it does not delete more than one duplicate node. Neither does it return false when there are no duplicate values:

```
1
2
3
4
5
15
70

RemoveDuplicatesSorted function output:
0
1
2
3
4
5
15
70
```

This is my function:

```
 bool RemoveDuplicatesSorted(struct node* head){
        struct node* current = head;
        bool result = false;
        while (current != NULL && current->next != NULL){
            if (current->data == current->next->data){
                struct node* temp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                delete temp;
                result=true;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
        current=nullptr;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Pardon the obvious, but don't you have to, you know. put duplicates *in* the list before you take any out ? Your list has no duplicates. The function returns false (which prints as `0` because you didn't enable `std::boolalpha` on your stream).

Comment: Is there any place in particular where I should enable boolalpha? Like where shall I put it in?

Comment: `cout << std::boolalpha << RemoveDuplicatesSorted(head);` would work.